# Qt: Finding memory leaks and errors

Tags: qt, memory, runtime, memory-leaks

I'm developing an application in Qt, and I'm having problems debbuging the application to find errors that crash my application with a runtime errors. Errors like array access out of bounds or wrong pointers access.

QT Creator simply doens't recognize this runtime error. All I have is the exit code, and sometimes an assert fail message in the application output. Something like:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file c:/Qt/2010.05/qt/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 463
```

How can I find the point where this access is being made?
I tried running gdb on my app executable, but after the application exits with an error code (03 in this above example) there's no backtrace (no stack available).

I have VS installed, and sometimes it asks to debug the exception (not this case :/) but even so, doens't recognize mingw32 debug symbols and only gives me a dissasembled view.

Ideally I would have QT Creator dump stack before such asserts that crash my application. Any tips?

Comment: The Qt Creator debugger mode doesn't work for you? That'd be weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having problems debugging that, try creating your own [message handling function](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) for Qt's debug/warning messages, and putting a breakpoint in that function.  Then you're program should stop whenever one of those messages is printed.